# How to Handle Third Party's Web View in Test Scripts witten in Robotium

Tags: java, android, robotium

I am using robotium tool for wirting the test scripts for an application . I wanna know how do I handle the third party's webview(i.e, Login) in my application .

For example, if I have a button `Checkout With Paypal` and when I click on it i get a login page from Paypal third party, which asks for the following

```
Login ID:
Password:
```

Then how do click on the above to text boxes in the test script and enter the appropriate text in that.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the webview is external to your application then im afraid to tell you that when using robotium it will be impossible to test what you want. Robotium can only inject events into your applications process which this will sadly not be a part of.

If however it is within your application then you are (slightly) in luck. You can interac with the webview, however robotium currently does not have any way to interact with elements inside webviews. It is possible to do this though, you have to fire in javascript yourself to interact with the web page. This is a bit of a pain but products such as https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android do it nicely so you can look at their implementation.

There is a third option, get the developers to fake the section of the application for your tests. Then add in a test that runs on a version without the faking to check that the correct intent is fired using an intent filter, that should cover both bases.

Comment: If you found it to be useful you can always up-vote the answer/accept it to let other people more easily know it is helpful.